# 8-in on stuck in boot mode recovery in Chinese

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, boot-loop

8-in on tablet stuck in boot mode. It keeps going arrow up, down, up, down through recovery, fast boot, and normal boot. It won't stop unless I hold all three buttons down, then I can get it to the recovery page which is in Chinese.

I have factory reset it and rebooted it, but it still goes back to the boot mode. Tried all the buttons. Help

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Based on current information, looks like the physical buttons are stuck, thus forcing the device to always boot into recovery due to the key combination. I think you have to bring your device to the repair shop and have it checked unless you want to try disassembling it yourself.